# Hibernate problem with connect data base - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I have problem with connect to data base, hibernate shows me error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/NamingStrategy$SuffixingRandom$BaseNameResolver
```

My test class is very simple:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutorialdb");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();
}
```

}

In my project is exist file byte-buddy-1.10.2.jar, where is the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure it's in your classpath? Check to make sure your IDE/build system has the .jar registered as a library and build again.

Comment: Ok this is good sugestion for me, I have see that I have create hibernate library in modulepath, what is difference between modulepath and classpath ?

Comment: The module path is where the compiler looks for modules, the classpath is where the compiler looks for classes within those modules. If you don't have a modular program, the module path isn't something you need to worry about, but in both cases you need to make sure the library is in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Applicable for maven project only

try to delete jar file from path /.m2/net/bytebuddy. try to build maven project again.(may be downloaded jar was corrupted)

In case of standalone project add jar at classpath.

hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

For modular Java project, just add

- *module-info.java*

  requires net.bytebuddy;
- *build.gradle (if any used)*

  runtimeOnly 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.1'